# Keycloak docker container throws `java.net.UnknownHostException` during startup

Tags: java, docker, keycloak

I'm trying to setup a keycloak container on my docker host. Unfortunately the keycloak container can't connect to my db container and always throws a `java.net.UnknownHostException`.

My `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '2' 

services:
  keycloak:
      image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
      container_name: keycloak
      restart: always
      networks:
        - webgateway
        - keycloak-net
      environment:
        - DB_VENDOR=MYSQL
        - DB_ADDR=keycloak-db
        - DB_DATABASE=keycloak
        - DB_USER=keycloak
        - DB_PASSWORD=password
        - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
        - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=password
      depends_on:
        - keycloak-db

  keycloak-db:
      image: mysql:5.7
      container_name: keycloak-db
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - /var/keycloak/database:/var/lib/mysql
      networks:
        - keycloak-net
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=keycloak
        - MYSQL_USER=keycloak
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password

networks:
  keycloak-net:
  webgateway:
    external:
      name: docker_webgateway
```

The error message:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: keycloak-db: Name or service not known,
    at java.base/java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method),
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929),
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1515),
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848),
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505),
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364),
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298),
    at com.mysql.jdbc@8.0.19//com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:132),
    at com.mysql.jdbc@8.0.19//com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65),
    ... 64 more,
,
23:44:04,490 FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to database,
```

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

P.S. The docker host is running locally so don't worry about my weak passwords.

Comment: `depends_on` can be a bit unpredictable. Better to put the `keycloak-db` first in the compose file

Comment: @surfer190 That's it. Thank you. Never thaught that `depends_on` doesn't work as I expected. Post your comment as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @surfer190, That's not true. It doesn't matter, wherever you put depends_on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flag `depends_on` only ensures the order in which container is started but not whether the container is ready to serve the requests or not and that's what is happening here, where SQL container is started but it's not ready to receive the requests as it takes time. Please follow the below commands and the file, in which I added the `health checks` as well in docker-compose and you need to change the version to `2.1 or higher`.

**Create an external docker network**

```
docker network create docker_webgateway
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
      container_name: keycloak
      restart: always
      networks:
        - webgateway
        - keycloak-net
      environment:
        - DB_VENDOR=MYSQL
        - DB_ADDR=keycloak-db
        - DB_DATABASE=keycloak
        - DB_USER=keycloak
        - DB_PASSWORD=password
        - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
        - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=password
      depends_on:
        - keycloak-db
  keycloak-db:
      image: mysql:5.7
      container_name: keycloak-db
      restart: always
      healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
          timeout: 20s
          retries: 10
      volumes:
        - /var/keycloak/database:/var/lib/mysql
      networks:
        - keycloak-net
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=keycloak
        - MYSQL_USER=keycloak
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
networks:
  keycloak-net:
  webgateway:
    external:
      name: docker_webgateway
```

**Create the stack by running the below command**

```
docker-compose up
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain more about the `healthcheck` stuff? I'm not able to use a version higher than 2.

Comment: Health-check is only enabled after version 2.1 . Healthchecks are used to check whether the service is ready to serve your requests or not before it starts accepting any requests

Comment: Please check this for reference as well. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck

Comment: I hope this answers your question